# how to get the length of DIVs after creating them

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im making an `$http` (angular) post, and then drawing there on `ng-repeat` some DIVs.

I need to know afterwards how many DIVs I've just created and then making some `DOM` manupulations in `JQuery`.

this is my code :

```
function ContactController($scope, $http,$location) {

$http.post('/Home/MakeThings', '{}').then(
function (obj) {


    $scope.questionsArr = obj.data;
    console.log($scope.questionsArr);

    var numBox = $('div[class^="boxQ"]').length;
    console.log(numBox);

    $scope.changeRoute = function (myPath) {
        console.log($scope.myPath);
        $location.path(myPath);
    }

},
function (error) {

});
```

}

I cant access

> $('div[class^="boxQ"]')

because I guess, It has not drawn yet by the ng-repeat .

what can I do in order to select it.

Comment: If your ng-repeat is driven off the questionsArr that you put on $scope, then it would just be the number of items in that. Just check questionsArr.length to know the number of divs that are created. Usually best to try to limit jquery operations within angular controllers.

Comment: thats great but I need to make a DOM manipulation as well. like adding a css , animate the DIVs within the ng-repeat and so on

Comment: Why don't you make a directive then and do your DOM manipulations in them. Will post fiddle shortly.

Comment: Having selectors in the controller is a strong indication of doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but I think the directive to be able to do whatever manipulation you want to do is the way to go. The example makes a questionsArr array on the $scope. These are shown with an ng-repeat and a custom-directive. The directive is what does the manipulation. I am toggling the boxQ class on click of the element.

```
var mod = angular.module("myApp", []);

mod.controller("MainController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.questionsArr = [
        "What is your name?",
        "Where do you live?"
    ];
});

mod.directive("questionBox", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            //elem refers to the jQuery/jqLite
            //element of the directive (e.g. <div questionBox></div).

            //Just toggling class on click
            elem.on("click", function () {
                elem.toggleClass("boxQ");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div ng-repeat="q in questionsArr">
        <div question-box>{{q}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F44Bs/). Again, it is best to limit any type of selectors/DOM manipulation within the controller as this sort of thing is what directives are made for.